# Navigate through XmlNode

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

Given this XML:

```
<o name="" type="product.567" id="5">
 <pl>
  <p name="product.articleNumber">413221</p>            
  <p name="product.width">2.200</p>
 </pl>
</o>
<o name="" type="product.678" id="6">
 <pl>
  <p name="product.articleNumber">1233123</p>       
  <p name="product.width">8.199</p>
 </pl>
</o>
```

In a first step, I want to select all product nodes . After that, I want to iterate through the nodelist and get the articleNumber and width of each product. I don't want to select all articleNumbers right away, because I want them to be linked to the product.

I tried to generate a nodelist using

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("File.xml");

klvNdList = doc.SelectNodes("//o");
```

Now I want to get the attributes of each node by

```
foreach(XmlNode klv in klvNdList)
{

 XmlNode child = klv.SelectSingleNode("//p[@name='product.articleNumber']");
 string theThingIWant = child.InnerText;

}
```

Unfortunaly it doesn't work and I only get empty texts.

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. It is missing a root node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use newer Net XML library XML Linq that replaces the legacy Xml library

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var products = doc.Descendants("o")
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                    type = (string)x.Attribute("type"),
                    id = (int)x.Attribute("id"),
                    properties = x.Descendants("p").Select(y => new { name = (string)y.Attribute("name"), value = (string)y }).ToList()
                }).ToList();
        }
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The only problem with this code is, that I get every property in the XML for every product. I only want the corresponding property for every product, could you help me with that?

Comment: Are you sure?   The code has a list of "o" tags and only the properties for each "o" is listed.  So you have a two dimension array.  Dimension 1 is the "o" tags and dimension 2 are the properties.  You have a table where the rows are the "o" and the columns are the properties for the row.

Comment: You're right! For some reason the first product contains all "p" properties, but the others work exactly as you explained. It's probably some issue with the xml-structure, but that's no problem, because the first "o" Descendant is not a product anyway. I'm incredibly thankful, you saved my day! Thank you!!!